How to add values to dataframe based on jump through columns based on a specific number?
I have a dataframe like df:
df = pd.DataFrame({'Months': [4, 3], 'Type': ['A', 'B'], 1: [0, 1], 2: [0, 1], 3: [2, 1], 4: [2, 0], 5: [0, 0], 6: [0, 0], 7: [0, 0], 8: [0, 0], 9: [0, 0]})

   Months Type  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9
0       4    A  0  0  2  2  0  0  0  0  0
1       3    B  1  1  1  0  0  0  0  0  0

For each row, I would like look at the value in df["Months"] (this will be the number of columns we should "jump"). If in df[1] or beyond there is a value higher than 0, I would like to jump n columns, based on the number in df["Months"] and then add that same number, but multiplied by -1.
So, the result should be like this:
df = pd.DataFrame({'Months': [4, 3], 'Type': ['A', 'B'], 1: [0, 1], 2: [0, 1], 3: [2, 1], 4: [2, 0], 5: [0, -1], 6: [0, -1], 7: [0, -1], 8: [-2, 0], 9: [-2, 0]})

   Months Type  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9
0       4    A  0  0  2  2  0  0  0 -2 -2
1       3    B  1  1  1  0 -1 -1 -1  0  0

Anyone could help me?

Could you clarify the rule on the example of the first row? (1) You take 4 from "Months". (2) You jump to which column — 4 (4:[2, 0])? (3) What do you do next — take the value from the 4th column, which is 2? (4) What's next — you jump again on 4 columns to reach column 8:[-2, 0]? (5) What's next — you multiply all the following columns after the 8th on the negative value you picked up from the (3) step?

For example, in the first row that df["Months"] is 4. The first time it finds a value different than 0 should be in df[3]. Than we should jump the next 4 columns and add that value again, but now multiplied to -1...that should be -2. After this, it should do the same thing for the next column or where it finds a value different than 0

Could you clarify the add the value again? You pick the value from df[3], multiply it by -1 and put it into the df[8]? What if df[8] has non-zero number? By jump do you mean adding jump value + 1 to the index (jumpy by 4 from df[3] means going to df[3+4+1])? After this, it should do the same thing do you mean then we go to the df[4] and repeat the operation? When do we stop the algorithm then?

What do you need help with exactly? Like, what have you tried, and where are you stuck? There are multiple parts to this task, so it's not clear which one you're having difficulty with. For example, do you know how to use df.apply() and Series.shift()? You might want to read Why is "Can someone help me?" not a useful question?

"add ... but multiplied by -1" - Isn't that just a long way of saying "subtract"?

This part of the description might be confusing: "... the number in df["Months"] and then add that same number ..." since "that same number" sounds like it's referring to "the number in df["Months"]"

Starting with:
   Months Type  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9
0       4    A  0  0  2  2  0  0  0  0  0
1       3    B  1  1  1  0  0  0  0  0  0

Doing:
# Move these columns to the index.
df = df.set_index(["Months", "Type"])

# Apply a per-row function that shifts all values by Months + 1 
# and then multiplies by -1.
# Add the original and modified dfs together.
out = df + df.apply(
    lambda x: x.shift(x.name[0] + 1, fill_value=0).mul(-1), 
    axis=1,
)

# Reset the index.
out = out.reset_index()

Output:
   Months Type  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9
0       4    A  0  0  2  2  0  0  0 -2 -2
1       3    B  1  1  1  0 -1 -1 -1  0  0

